# How do I generalize a makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here's a simple makefile:

```
view: hello.dvi
    xdvi hello.dvi

hello.dvi: hello.latex
    latex hello.latex
```

typing 'make' compiles and displays my latex document.

Suppose I've got several different files a.latex, b.latex, etc.

How can I make it so that 'make hello' builds and displays hello, 'make a' builds and displays a, etc, without having to write everything out several times.

Can I make it so that 'make' rebuilds and displays everything available?

Can I throw away the intermediate and log files, which are rarely of interest if the make succeeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNUMake actually has a built-in rule to build `.tex` files :

```
# default
TEX = tex

%.dvi: %.tex
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(TEX) $<
```

Following that, you can write your own rule to build `.latex` files :

```
%.dvi: %.latex
    latex $<
```

---

> *How can I make it so that 'make hello' builds and displays hello, 'make a' builds and displays a, etc, without having to write everything out several times.*

You need a rule like this one :

```
%: %.dvi
    xdvi $<
```

*Can I make it so that 'make' rebuilds and displays everything available?*

Add an `all` rule at the top of the other rules :

```
all: $(wildcard *.dvi)
```

To sum everything up, your makefile could now looks like :

```
all: $(wildcard *.dvi)

%: %.dvi
    xdvi $<

%.dvi: %.latex
    latex $<
```

Comment: Yes, and for completeness, I'll add that this is indeed a GNU Make extension.  [Posix make](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html) (which is descended from BSD make) has 'suffix rules' which are less flexible, but which allow you to achieve broadly the same thing.

Comment: Pattern rules are not specific to GNU Make: other makes (Sun make, FreeBSD make) also have them.

Comment: You can replace `$(wildcard *.dvi)` with just `*.dvi` here.